# Spark-shell --conf option for Kryos/Java serializer

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I need to launch the spark shell with custom classes using registerKryoClasses method as mentioned in the [spark help page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) .

Now as mentioned in the page I cannot recreate the sc variable after launching the spark shell and hence need to provide the option --conf while launching the spark-shell command.

What should be the option value with --conf so that it is equivalent to the following update:

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[ArrayBuffer[String]], classOf[ListBuffer[String]]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to use Javaserializer instead of Kryos serializer worked for me:

```
spark-shell --conf 'spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer'
```

Edit: just figured out how to use the options. We can do the following:

```
--conf 'spark.kryo.classesToRegister=scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer'
```